# Rails carrierwave error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, fog

I'm using carrierwave and fog to upload files in my app.  I upgraded all my gems and now receive this error `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

```
<%= link_to image_tag(listing.image_url(:thumb).to_s,
    :class => 'popup-image'),
    listing,
    :class => 'big-image-link' if listing.image?  %>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just reverted back to fog version 1.3 and it worked again.